# How to make flutter gridview scalable.?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

Used sizer to make widgets responsive. it work fine on large screen and also a space available for ads after grid view items. But on small gridview item take whole screen and no space for ads after grid view items . how to keep the gridview constant for all screens.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to assign width and height depending on MediaQuery for you gridview item and use same values as  **childAspectRatio** inside gridDelegate like this

```
gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
        crossAxisCount: 3,
        childAspectRatio: (itemsWidth) / (itemHeight),
      ),
```

That will make your widget responsive

here an example

[image]

example.dart

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  List<String> items = List.generate(100, (index) => "index 1");

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    final height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    return  Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
        ),
        body: GridView.builder(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
          physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
          itemCount: items.length,
          shrinkWrap: true,
          gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
            crossAxisCount: 3,
            crossAxisSpacing: 12,
            mainAxisSpacing: 12,
            childAspectRatio: (width * .3) / (height * .1),
          ),
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return GridViewItem(
              info: items[index],
              itemHeight: height * .1,
              itemWidth: width * .3,
            );
          },
        ));
  }
}


class GridViewItem extends StatelessWidget {
  final double itemWidth;
  final double itemHeight;
  final String info;
  const GridViewItem({Key? key,required this.itemHeight,required this.itemWidth,required this.info}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: itemWidth,
      height: itemHeight,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
        color: Colors.red
      ),
      child: Center(
        child: Text(
            info,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: i tried this but still getting different view on different screens